# Self-hosted Rke2 Load balancer No External IP

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, rke2

This is potentially a noob question, but I cannot figure it out on my own even after researching. I have my own HA K8s set up with RKE2. All works fine, NodePort services are accessible. The rancher ingress allows me to configure DNS mappings, etc.

Now my problem: if I scale up my deployments then I figure I need a load balancer service that randomly routes to the scaled up instances (trying this with a 3 instance neo4j db). Deployments work fine all cluster instances are accessible via the NodePort service that comes with the neo4j Helm. But, my load balancer service does not get an external IP. I know that a cloud provider would typically assign it, but what if this would be a, e.g, airgap installation? Who would do it (assigning the IP) then? And, would I even need it in a Rancher RKE2 cluster? Should I simply let my nginx-ingress know that there is a lb service and the ingress deals with the external IP situation?

Maybe someone even has a tutorial or reference for me?

Thanks for your time and the help!

Rke2 install, rancher working, Neo4j nodeport accesible, ingress working

Comment: Hi @cojack20 is this something you ever made any progress on? I have the exact same question

Comment: Yes, this was indeed a noob question. Look into metallb. Install the manifest and done ;)

Answer (score 1):

yes, cojack20 was right, the configuration is tuned to that in the MetalLB documentation.
must be instructed to do so via the IPAddressPool CR.

```
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: IPAddressPool
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  addresses:
  - 192.168.10.0/24
```